# How to write a varying matrix in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have this equation system a set of `1 ≤ n ≤ 30`

```
−(2 + α)x1 + x2 = b1,
xj−1 − (2 + α)xj + xj+1 = bj , for 2 ≤ j ≤ 29,
x29 − (2 + α)x30 = b30.
```

α = 1
We assume that the membrane is held at the end points (i.e x0 = 0 and x31 = 0). There is no weight on the membrane so all bj = 0 for j = 1 . . . 30 except for j = 6 where a load is applied: b6 = 2.

I want to calculate LU factorization of the system .
I do not know how to implement the left side of the system in matlab.
The right side I made it like this :

```
b=[0 0 0 0 0 6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]';
```

How to do the left side?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a typo in b above? should the 6th element be 2 not 6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear why you have included the entire linear system if you are only interested in the LU factorization of A? Regardless, here is some code which generates your A matrix as described above, and solves the linear system and shows the LU factorization.

```
% equation A*X = b

b = zeros(30,1);
b(6) = 2;
alpha = 1;

A = zeros(30, 30);

A(1, 1) = -(2 + alpha);
A(1, 2) = 1;

for i = 2:29
    A(i, i-1) = 1;
    A(i, i) = -(2 + alpha);
    A(i, i+1) = 1;
end

A(30, 29) =  1;
A(30, 30) = -(2 + alpha);
```

You can then get the LU factorization using `lu(A)` or solve the linear system of equations using `linsolve(A,b)`.

Comment: `A = -(2+alpha)*eye(30) + diag(ones(29,1),1) + diag(ones(29,1),-1)` is sufficient instead of the looping.

Comment: God bless you ... thank you all for help brothers .. I understand much better now  :)